# Easier way to copy the path to a file or directory to the clipboard in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, path, clipboard

To accomplish this I've been right-clicking the file or directory and then selecting Show in Windows Explorer, and then copying the path out of the address bar.

Is there an add-on or macro that can make this task easier?

I'm aware that you can drag a file from Solution Explorer into the editor and it will write out the path, but when doing web development I don't always want the server path, sometimes I want the local path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at PowerCommands extension

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99?SRC=Home

Among others, it contains "Copy Path" command for files and folders

**UPD:** Also, another option: right-click the tab of open document and there will be "Copy Full Path" command. It's built-in, no extensions needed

Comment: Woo Hoo!  I've been missing that functionality since I switched IDEs!  Thanks MadBender!

Comment: Hmm odd, I ran VS as administrator to setup the extension but the items aren't appearing in the context menu.   I also noticed that in Tools->Options...Power Commands all command items are checked.

Comment: Works well for me. Try to modify and save the settings, check for conflicts with other extensions, install SP1 if you don't have it. Maybe it will fix the problem

Comment: I used it with SP1 and without, and I don't think it's main reason. Conflict with other extensions is more likely. Do you have any?

Comment: Unfortunately not available for VS 2022

Answer (score 9):

You can just **select the file**  in the 'Solution Explorer' file list and hit **CTRL+C**. It automatically copies the file path to your clipboard.

Comment: Correct. It seems to work only on folders that have the "folder" icon and on regular files, **not** on solution or project or properties items.

Comment: It copies the file itself, not the path.

Answer (score 1):

I've found one more option of how to solve it without plugins (for VS 2015 and above; not certain about previous versions)
Go to "Tools" -> "Customize..." -> "Commands" tab.
Choose "Context menu:" and "Project and Solution Context Menus | Item" and you can add any existing Command.

In order to copy path, choose Category "File" and "Copy Full Path" command. Will add button only for files in Solution Explorer.
This works for projects as well but you should choose "Project and Solution Context Menus | Project" (copy path of .vcxproj file).

It doesn't work for solutions and I don't understand actually why.

Comment: in vs2022 it's a bit weird -- it works for solution, and in code window, but not for project or project item.

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

You can set your own shortcut keys for anything. The two that are most relevant to this post are "File.CopyFullPath" and "File.CopyRelativePath".
I created my shortcut to just be used in "Text Editor" and it has worked great.

This was asked for VS2010 and I'm using VS2019, so it is an old question, but still relevant. I knew about the file header right click menu, but for some reason I didn't think about the shortcut keys until I read this question. Posting in case this results in a quicker fix for anyone else.

Comment: strangely, File.CopyRelativePath doesn't work for me as a shortcut, though I've set it in the keyboard settings in VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

The CTRL+C doesn't work for me on MSVS 2017.
Use the copy as path extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexEyler.CopyasPath&ssr=false#review-details).
Then right click on file in solution explorer -> Copy as path (or assign a shortcut).
I find that it works very well.